How to use JQAssistant internal node labels in custom concept
I currently have a look into JQAssistant and how I can utilize it in my projects.
One thing, I want to do, is to use it to verify ADRs. Therefore, I want to check, if there are any JQA Constraints available for a given ADR.
I planned to use the internal JQA node labels JQAssistant, Rule and Constraint for it and wrote the following concept, which creates a relation :ENSURED_BY between a ADR and a JQA Constraint having the same ID.
<concept id="adr:matchingConstraint">
        <requiresConcept refId="adr:document"/>
        <description>Links ADRs with JQL Constraints which ensure the ADR</description>
        <cypher><![CDATA[
            match (a:Adr)
            match (c:Constraint) where c.id STARTS WITH a.adrId
            merge (a)-[r:ENSURED_BY]->(c)
            return a.adrId as adr, c.id, type(r)
        ]]></cypher>
    </concept>

The Cypher Query it self works fine.
But as soon as I want to apply the concept, I get the following error:
[WARNING] --[ Concept Application Failure ]----------------------------------
[WARNING] Concept: adr:matchingConstraint
[WARNING] Severity: MINOR
[WARNING] Number of rows: 0
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Links ADRs with JQL Constraints which ensure the ADR
[WARNING] -------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] 

Problem seems to be, that the JQA related node labels are not yet set, when this concept is applied. When I run analyze a second time, the concept gets applied with no errors.
I want to use <requiresConcept /> to ensure the execution order, but I was not able to find, which concept creates the JQA labels.
Does anybody know, how I can wait for those labels?
A work around would be to create my own concept and labels based on the XML plugin but since JQA already provides this, I think the better solution would be to use those.

Please don't add solutions inside the question. Consider creating an actual answer

The nodes representing executed rules (e.g. labeled with :jQAssistant:Concept) are created right after executing each according rule. The intented purpose is to track the result status and enable skipping rules for a subsequent analyze.
So the safest way for your use case indeed is to run a second analyze, as otherwise it would be difficult to ensure that the concept above is executed as the last rule.

Thanks for the clarification. That explains a lot :)

For completeness, I updated the question with my workaround

UPDATE/SOLUTION:
As pointed out by Dirk Mahler in the accepted answer, using the internal concepts as references will not work.
For completeness, here is my workaround using the XML parser:
MATCH (adr:Adr)
MATCH (e:Xml:Element {name: 'constraint'})-->(attr:Xml:Attribute {name: 'id'})
WHERE attr.value STARTS WITH adr.adrId
MERGE (adr)-[r:ENSURED_BY]->(constraint:AdrConstraint {adrId: adr.adrId, id: attr.value})
RETURN adr.adrId, type(r), constraint.id

For everybody who is interested in the whole setup, here is the link to my jqa sample project I used for a blog post:
https://github.com/stmu-zuhlke/jqa-sample
